# How can I configure IIS 6 programmatically?

Tags: c#, iis, configuration, iis-6

I see that there is a nice library `Microsoft.Web.Administration` that allows you to configure IIS 7. It appears that `Microsoft.Web.Administration` doesn't work for IIS6, so I am trying to see if someone can provide some alternative suggestions.

I am building a Windows Form Application that will allow you to implement all the properties required to configure (Website, Virtual directories, Application pools...etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure IIS6 you will have to revert to the System.Directory services.

```
string iisPath = "IIS://localhost/W3svc/1/Root";
DirectoryEntry IISRootEntry = new DirectoryEntry(iisPath);
```

and take it from there.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

There is a massive VB script called [ADSUtil.vbs](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d3df4bc9-0954-459a-b5e6-7a8bc462960c.mspx?mfr=true) that lives in IIS's admin directory that can be used to configure IIS in a scripted, if not programmatic, way.  You could either call out to it, or read it and rip off its internals.